# Angular - Stop observable interval

Tags: angular, observable

l Created an Observable with RXJS interval and pass an array with img src, and i used an async pipe in template to subscribe the src value to looping images .

```js
  index: number;
  image$: Observable<any>;
     stoploop : boolean = false


     play() {

      this.image$.subscribe(()=>{

        let imgs: string[]=[
          '1',
          '2',
          '3',
          '4',
          '5',
          '6',
          '7',
          '8',

        ];

        this.index=imgs.length;
        this.image$ =interval(400).pipe(map(()=>{
          this.isImageLoaded = true
          return imgs[imgs.length - this.index++ % imgs.length -1]
        })),startWith(imgs[0],takeWhile(()=>this.stoploop))

      })

        }



      stop() {

           this.image$.unsubscribe()

        console.log(this.stoploop=true)
      }
```

The problem is when l click on fun stop interval is not stop i have Error `Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'. Did you mean 'subscribe'?`

Comment: this.image$.unscubscribe();

Comment: i have only `this.image$.subscribe()`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but it is often better to prefer `takeUntil` over `takeWhile`, [because `takeUntil` cancels the source `Observable` immediately](https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `takeWhile` is not in the `pipe`.

```
this.stoploop = false;
this.image$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  startWith(imgs[0]),
  takeWhile(()=>!this.stoploop),
  map(() => {
    this.isImageLoaded = true
    return imgs[imgs.length - this.index++ % imgs.length -1]
  })
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2spwne?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Great , the fun `stop()` he is working , but when i click again on fun play() he doesn't resume looping !

Comment: Yes, because the `takeWhile`  will be complete Observable.

Comment: So its possible to make him resume loop ?

Comment: add `this.stoploop = false;` to the up line.